# rerender and save the record when a field is edited issue

Tags: visualforce, onchange

Hi I'm quite new to to VF and having an isssue getting something to work. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is when  a field is edited:QuoteLineItem.QoS__c is changed ( a boolean field) it rerenders and saves the record.

Here is my page :

```
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputPanel id="panel">
<apex:pageBlockSection id="AttachmentNames">       
    <apex:inputField value="{!QuoteLineItem.QoS__c}" rendered="{!IF(QuoteLineItem.QoS__c=TRUE , TRUE , FALSE)  }"/> <br/>

    <apex:commandlink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" />   

</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Do you want to do some action when the field value is changed?

Comment: Hi Ankita - correct :) I would like to save the entire record whenever the QoS__c field is changed or any field on this page

Answer (score 0):

Add an apex:actionSupport below the apex:inputField.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!QuoteLineItem.QoS__c}" rendered="{!IF(QuoteLineItem.QoS__c=TRUE , TRUE , FALSE)  }">
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!Action_to_be_performed}" event="onchange" rerender="Id of the block to reload">
</apex:inputField>
```

Refer [apex actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) for more details.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Do mark it as useful if it resolved your issue.